# aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey not being read

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, properties

I have a spring boot application which uses S3 buckets. 
According to Amazon (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html) the order should be:

> 1. In system environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.
> 2. In the Java system properties: aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey.
> 3. In the default credentials file (the location of this file varies by platform).
> 4. In the instance profile credentials, which exist within the instance metadata associated with the IAM role for the EC2 instance.

However my code is ignoring the aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey from application.properties.

```
public AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
    AWSCredentialsProviderChain instanceProvider = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
    builder.setCredentials(instanceProvider);
    builder.setRegion(region);
    return builder.build();
}
```

It works when I use it on a EC2 instance, but it fails when I try to use it locally for development.

UPDATE:

also tried with

```
        DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain instanceProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        System.out.println(instanceProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId());
        System.out.println(instanceProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey());
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(instanceProvider).withRegion(region).build();
```

and it failed as well. When I print the access key it shows the right value and the secret something different (I assume it is encrypted due to security reasons).
If I use BasicCredentials it work.

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName, secretKey);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).disableChunkedEncoding().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the code that you've posted works on EC2, because [AWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) expects a list of providers.

What you want instead is [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html).

However, you shouldn't need an explicit credentials provider (and this may be why it works), because `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()` creates a builder with all defaults set (which includes the default provider chain).

If changing the class doesn't solve your problem, then you'll need to edit your question to show (1) the command line that you're using (redacting the keys), and (2) the *exact* error message, copied from the terminal.

Comment: True, I forgot to say that I tried with `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` and it gives me access denied. The keys are correct on the file but if I print them the secret key is shown differently.